# 3D slider with css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create 3D slider using CSS 3-D Transformations. I am not so good in web designing.

Here is what I have done so far.

1. Html code.

   ```
   <html>

   <body>
       <section id="f4">

       <h3>SCREENY</h3>
       <h1>Zobacz co potrafi nowy iOS 8</h1>

       <small>Oto kilka screenów dla zobrazowania jego możliwości </small>


       <center>
       <ul class="My3D_slider">

                   <li><img src="http://enagrody.com/iphone6v3/images/ss6.jpg"  width="320" height="568"></li>

                   <li><img src="http://enagrody.com/iphone6v3/images/ss2.jpg"  width="320" height="568"></li>

                   <li><img src="http://enagrody.com/iphone6v3/images/ss3.png"  width="320" height="568"></li>

                   <li><img src="http://enagrody.com/iphone6v3/images/ss4.png"  width="320" height="568"></li>

                   <li><img src="http://enagrody.com/iphone6v3/images/ss5.jpg"  width="320" height="568"></li>

                 </ul> 

       </center>

       </section>

   </body>
   ```

2.CSS CODES.

```
.My3D_slider{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
transform-style: preserve-3d;

}

.My3D_slider li img {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 116px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    border:2px solid black;
}

.My3D_slider li:nth-child (img) {transform: translateZ(-382.256px) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(382.256px);}

.My3D_slider li:nth-child (img) {transform: translateZ(-382.256px) rotateY(-72deg) translateZ(382.256px);}

.My3D_slider li:nth-child (img) {transform: translateZ(-382.256px) rotateY(-144deg) translateZ(382.256px);}

.My3D_slider li:nth-child (img) {transform: translateZ(-382.256px) rotateY(-288deg) translateZ(382.256px);}

.My3D_slider li:nth-child (img) {transform: translateZ(-382.256px) rotateY(-576deg) translateZ(382.256px);}
```

3.The final results should look like this 
[image]
How Can I accomplish this without using jquery? If it's not possible without using jquery please provide some tutorial how can accomplish this using Jquery.

Comment: You can always use a jQuery plugin such as Flipster.js https://github.com/drien/jquery-flipster

Comment: thank you, there is no simple way to do this without using plugin..?

Comment: I tried to use as little jQuery as possible, the animations are done with CSS keyframes, here is an example: http://codepen.io/matthiasjee/pen/xRmgdw

Comment: Thank you, I managed it by using 3D Transformation.

Comment: Here is the best plugin to create 3D carousel : https://jascarousel.github.io/jascarousel/